# How to extract folder image url from json file to .js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I want to extract my folder image url from JSON file(or Suggest any other) to display in my .js file but my method doesn't seems to work. Please look at the code:
Lenses.js:

```
import lenses from './lens.json'
const Lenses = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <>
    <div className="lensescon">
    {lenses.map((lens) => (
      
      <Lenspro heading={lens.heading} price={lens.price} para="Ideal for everyday use" img={lens.img}/>
                  ))}
        
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

lens.json:

```
[

    {
      "heading": "Lens#1",
      "price": "5",
      "img": "./lens/lens1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "heading": "Lens#2",
      "price": "3",
      "img": "./lens/lens2.jpg"
    }]
```

Please look what I am doing wrong or suggest a different method to map my images.

Comment: The way how you pass down the prop to `Lenspro` component is correct. Can you please share code for `Lenspro` component to see how is it trying to render it?

Comment: The code for lenspro is long but this how I am rendering the image: <img src={props.img} alt="g1" />